# addEventListener not working properly

Tags: javascript, closures, addeventlistener

I am new to JS, currently learning from multiple different sources, this is a simple catclicker game I am building with vanilla js. ***On line 75*** - I have an addeventlistner that is being called even after it's no longer selected. For example, it keeps counting even after the cat is no longer selected.

These are the instructions:

Visuals
 
1. The application should display
2. a list of at least 5 cats, listed by name
3. an area to display the selected cat

In the cat display area, the following should be displayed
1.the cat's name
 
2.a picture of the cat
 
3.text showing the number of clicks
 
4.The specifics of the layout do not matter, so style it however you'd like.

Interaction
 
1.When a cat name is clicked in the list, the cat display area should update to show the data for the selected cat.
2. The number of clicks in the cat area should be unique to each cat, and should increment when the cat's picture is clicked.

```js
   var cats = [{
     name: "Mr. Nibbles",
     img: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg',
     count: 0,
     id: 1
   }, {
     name: "Paws",
     img: "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99233806-bringing-home-new-cat-632x475.jpg",
     count: 0,
     id: 2
   }, {
     name: "Sphyx",
     img: "https://drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/31905196/1/?bust=1429232863&width=632&no_scale_up=1",
     count: 0,
     id: 3
   }, {
     name: "Millo",
     img: "https://drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/31905196/3/?bust=1429232864&width=632&no_scale_up=1",
     count: 0,
     id: 4
   }, {
     name: "Meowister",
     img: "https://drpem3xzef3kf.cloudfront.net/photos/pets/31505696/2/?bust=1425080994&width=632&no_scale_up=1",
     count: 0,
     id: 5
   }]

   function catList(array) {

     var listArea = document.getElementsByClassName('ListArea');

     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       var list = document.createElement('li');
       list.className = ("cat");
       list.innerHTML = array[i].name;

       listArea[0].appendChild(list);

       var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('cat');

     }

     for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
       elem[x].addEventListener("click", (function(numbcopy) {
         return function() {
           loadCat(cats, numbcopy);
         };
       })(x));
     }


     var displayPhoto = document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea')[0];
     var image = document.createElement('img');
     var cattile = document.createElement('h3');
     var catcount = document.createElement('p');
     displayPhoto.appendChild(image);
     displayPhoto.appendChild(cattile);
     displayPhoto.appendChild(catcount);


     function loadCat(array, i) {
       image.src = array[i].img;
       image.style.width = '600px';
       image.className = ("catphoto");
       image.id = (array[i].id);
       image.id = ("selected");

       cattile.innerHTML = array[i].name;

       catcount.innerHTML = array[i].count;

       var selected = document.querySelector("#selected");


       selected.addEventListener('click', function() {
         array[i].count = array[i].count + 1;
         catcount.innerHTML = array[i].count;
       });
     }
   }
   catList(cats);
```

```css
            body {

              margin-right: 80px;

              margin-left: 80px;

            }

            .col-1 {

              width: 25%;

              float: left;

            }

            .col-2 {

              width: 75%;

              float: right;

            }

            .col-2 img {

              margin-top: 20px;

            }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="ListArea col-1">
    <h1> Click on the cat</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="displayArea col-2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding listeners many times. You must add listener once out of `loadCat` function:

```
image.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var i = this.getAttribute('data-id');
  array[i].count = array[i].count + 1;
  catcount.innerHTML = array[i].count;
});
```

I added attribute `data-id` for define which cat was clicked.

And also `id` of cats in object must be started from `0`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7zoaj31/2/)